# unable add 2nd data to Access database using the GUI button

Tags: vb.net

i have try to add some data into the access database VIA VB2008, when i pull in no issue using their original function, where there is add, delete and save button on top of it, but when i am creating the function on the button, found that 1st data able to add, second data unable to add, it show "too many field to defined" appreciate someone can help out, i go through many link, i am copy exactly what they have done.

i have tried remove the ID (auto generate number in access) but still fail. no article on it

```
 If Button2.Text = "New" Then
            Try
                BEFOREBindingSource.AddNew()
                MsgBox("successful")
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Error during Add")
                Exit Sub
            End Try
 ElseIf Button2.Text = "Save" Then
            Try
                'Me.BEFOREBindingSource.EndEdit()
                ' Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.MPCINSPECTION2DataSet)
                BEFOREBindingSource.EndEdit()
                BEFORETableAdapter.Update(MPCINSPECTION2DataSet.BEFORE)

            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Error during save")
                Exit Sub
            End Try
End if
```

Comment: What kind of datasource is `BEFOREBindingSource` linked to? If it is an MS Access table, can you please show its structure?

Comment: No structure add, only one table are use in database